# Unable to connect internet in bridge mode in vmware

Tags: networking, windows-10, vmware, centos-7

I am trying to install CentOS 7 minimal in VMWare, but when I tried to connect Internet during the installation in bridged mode, it refused to connected and, after few seconds, it automatically disconnected. Here is the screenshot which I am talking about:

[image]

I have tried all possible combination, like entering a static IP and a few more things after I finished installing, but no luck.

Any idea what is wrong, as Internet is working fine in window 10.
Comment if you want more information.

Comment: I assume you mean Workstation. Use a NATed network, that will work.

Comment: No, I want host and vmware should be on same network so that I can access application from other PC,I want to be on bridged Adapter. @Zina

Comment: ok, what is your ipconfig output on your host and what network IP/subnet/GW did you set on the VM?

Comment: @Zina  I use IP from free pool, 
IP: 10.235.77.88
subnet: 255.255.0.0
gateway:10.235.10.2
I have also tried automatic ip assignment and my DHCP is running.

Comment: a /16 network, are you in a corporate environment? where is your DHCP? do you see the IP assignment on your DHCP? what are your PC network settings?

Comment: @Zina At the time of replying, I was doing that in my office but I think the issue is not with the network, although I don't have access to see the IP assignment. 
I have also tried in my home network which is running on 192.168.X.X network which is still not working. 
Is there any chances that the host machine (window 10) is causing the issue.
My host machine is using automatic IP assignment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85821/discussion-between-vinay-and-zina).

Answer (score 1):

**Configure Networks in Workstation**

I would suggest you configure additional networks in VMware's Workstation the following way:

1. Open "Edit" -> "Virtual Network Editor"
2. Click on "Change Settings"
3. Click "Yes" on UAC
4. Click "Add Network"
5. Select free VMnet network to be created
6. When new network is added select it
7. Select "Bridged (connect VMs directly to the external network)"
8. Select under "Bridged to" your netowrk adapter which you have connected your host to your network
9. Repeat steps 4 to 8 until you have created Bridged networks for all of your hosts NICs

**Configure your VM NICs setting**

Go to "Settings" of your VM and change the Network adapter setting "Network Connection" to "Custom: Specific virtual network" and try with each of the newly created networks if the VM will pick up an IP.

I have found out that the setting to "Bridged: Connected directly to the physical network" in the VM settings, does not always work, as this setting should automatically detect which hosts NIC to use.

With the above creation you can work around that limitation. 
Only thing to remember is to change the VM's NIC settings if you move you host's connection. Eg, moving from Wired to WiFi or from Home to Work.

**NOTE!**

If none of the networks at work will provide you an IP then your company's network is using some authentication protocol on the network which can prohibit IP assignment.

Comment: this response worth bookmaking - thanks